# how to handle / in mysql queries

Tags: mysql

There is a procedure that add customer to customer table. Procedure call is made dynamically from google endpoints. When I enter /\ then following query is made.

But there is issue of / (slash).It avoid the next parameters as / hide the purpose of ' (quote)

```
 call dim_add_customer('0','12','/\', '/\','2015-11-14','abc@xyz.com')
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/` does not escape anything. `\` does and thus has to be escaped itself as `\\`.

```
 call dim_add_customer('0','12','/\\', '/\\','2015-11-14','abc@xyz.com')
```

Comment: I am using python in Google API. Is there any way to do this automatically in python?